# Multiple mailbox deliveries in Postfix

Tags: postfix

I have a suspicion that what I'm trying to do is impossible, but I'll ask the question anyway.

If I'm using virtual domains, is it possible for an inbound address to deliver into multiple mailboxes without a rewrite?

To flesh things out a bit more, suppose I have the domain example.com and wish to set up the following deliveries:

@example.com -> mbox1
fred@example.com -> mbox2, mbox1
jim@example.com -> mbox3, mbox1

That is, I want a copy of any mail to the fred and jim addresses also delivered to the catchall mailbox for the domain.

I could do something similar using the virtual_alias_maps with lines like this:

@example.com catchall@example.com
fred@example.com fred@example.com catchall@example.com
jim@example.com jim@example.com catchall@example.com

(with appropriate entries in virtual_mailbox maps)

However, if I introduce the artificial catchall address, then the Delivered-To address will reflect this and I want to keep the original Delivered-To information in the catchall mailbox. I would have thought this isn't too bizarre a thing to want to do, so any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You want the `recipient_bcc_maps` option, with an `@example.com mbox1@${myhostname}` entry (or something like that).

Comment: Thanks! Interesting idea to use BCC, but I don't think it will work here. I should probably have emphasised that example.com is a virtual domain delivering to virtual mailboxes. The only address that is associated with mbox1 is the catchall address (@example.com) and unfortunately that doesn't work as the RHS in the BCC rule. If I were to instead use catchall@example.com as my RHS then that would indeed deliver a copy into mbox1, but the rewrite to that address would be reflected in the Delivered-To header, which is what I'm trying to avoid.